# Scroll to top button wont fadeOut

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am having trouble getting my scroll to top button to work. I know its a problem with another animation but I am not able to see what is causing the issue. The problem is when the other animation "starts when scroll hits 500" the scroll to top button will no longer fade out and disappear.

```
$.chain = function() {
    var promise = $.Deferred().resolve().promise();
    jQuery.each( arguments, function() {
      promise = promise.pipe( this );
    });
    return promise;
  };  

  function scrollTop(){
    if(typeof pageYOffset!= 'undefined'){
      return pageYOffset;
    }
    else{
      var b = document.body; //IE 'quirks'
      var d = document.documentElement; //IE with doctype
      d = (d.clientHeight)? d : b;
      return d.scrollTop;
    }
  }    

  $(window).on("scroll", function(){
    if(scrollTop() >= 600){
    $(window).off("scroll");
      var animations = $.chain(function() {
        return $('#animate1 img').fadeIn('slow').delay(400);
      }, function() {
        return $('#animate2 img').fadeIn('slow').delay(400);
      },  function() {
        return $('#animate3 img').fadeIn('slow');
      });
    };
});

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
var offset = 300;
var duration = 500;
jQuery(window).scroll(function() {
    if (jQuery(this).scrollTop() > offset) {
        jQuery('.scroll-top').fadeIn(duration);
    } else {
        jQuery('.scroll-top').fadeOut(duration);
    }
});
});
```

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Where are you trying to tell it to fade out at?  I only see fade in script.  Also, it looks like you are ending your `if (scrollTop() >= 600) {` with both an `}` and a simi-colon.  Just FYI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$(window).off("scroll");` is indeed removing `scroll` event which you're listening to fadeIn and fadeOut.

Although i havent tried it but an alternative would be to use [event namespacing](http://api.jquery.com/event.namespace/)?

something like below:

```
$.chain = function() {
    var promise = $.Deferred().resolve().promise();
    jQuery.each( arguments, function() {
      promise = promise.pipe( this );
    });
    return promise;
  };  

  function scrollTop(){
    if(typeof pageYOffset!= 'undefined'){
      return pageYOffset;
    }
    else{
      var b = document.body; //IE 'quirks'
      var d = document.documentElement; //IE with doctype
      d = (d.clientHeight)? d : b;
      return d.scrollTop;
    }
  }    

  $(window).on("scroll.foranimations", function(){ // event name
    if(scrollTop() >= 600){
    $(window).off("scroll.foranimations"); // event name
      var animations = $.chain(function() {
        return $('#animate1 img').fadeIn('slow').delay(400);
      }, function() {
        return $('#animate2 img').fadeIn('slow').delay(400);
      },  function() {
        return $('#animate3 img').fadeIn('slow');
      });
    };
});

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    var offset = 300;
    var duration = 500;
    jQuery(window).on("scroll.forfading", function() { // event name
        if (jQuery(this).scrollTop() > offset) {
            jQuery('.scroll-top').fadeIn(duration);
        } else {
            jQuery('.scroll-top').fadeOut(duration);
        }
    });
});
```

notice different event names `scroll.foranimations` and `scroll.forfading`

Comment: Thank you Varinder. I'm new to JQuery, makes sense after you explaining it. Do you know of any good JQuery debugging tool?

Comment: You could probably start by getting familiar ```console.log()``` ( https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/console.log ) for basic testing ```if ( someCondition ) { console.log( "the condition was true" ) } else { console.log("...") }```, for more advanced debugging, setting JS breakpoints ( https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/javascript-debugging ) is the way to go. You can do great things like break on certain events as well